# what is the error when integrating maven with Struts 1.3 with local project libraries?

Tags: maven, servlets, struts

I have some local jar files in my 'projectBaseDir/lib' location and i have added the directory with the following maven command

```
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mylibid</id>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

still, the following command shows that it doesn't find any library / showing errors.

> mvn clean install

Here is a screenshot - 
[image]

Comment: Because that's not what the layout of a repository looks like.http://doduck.com/adding-local-jar-in-maven-local-repository/. That said, it's a pretty useless way of doing dependency management since you get none of the actual benefits of using Maven for transitive dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder, let's say local-maven-repo at the root of your Maven project.

Just add a local repo inside your  of your pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repo</id>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/local-maven-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then for each external jar you want to install, go at the root of your project and execute:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=[GROUP] -DartifactId=[ARTIFACT] -Dversion=[VERS] -Durl=file:./local-maven-repo/ -DrepositoryId=local-maven-repo -DupdateReleaseInfo=true -Dfile=[FILE_PATH]
```

Comment: Make sure the jar is present at the root of your project into /local-maven-repo/com/jarName/1.5.3/jarName-1.5.3.jar